# How to set visibility from onAnimationUpdate

Tags: android, animation, lottie

I want to make some views in my app visible and some other views invisible when some animated value of those views is more than a specific value (say, 0.5f).

Something like this:

```
@Override
public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {

    if((float)animation.getAnimatedValue() >= 0.2){
        (View)animation.setVisibility(View.GONE); //Something like this
        
    }
}
```

As you know, `setVisibility()` function doesn't work!

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Here you are trying to set visibility of ValueAnimator. This wont work.

Try changing the visibility of actual views instead of ValueAnimator.

```
@Override
public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {

    if((float)animation.getAnimatedValue() >= 0.2){
        viewToBeMadeInvisible.setVisibility(View.GONE); //Like this
        
    }
}
```

**Update:** You could add AnimatorListenerAdapter to listen for animation end.

```
animation.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() 
{
    @Override

    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) 
    {
        //set your visibility code here.
    }
});
```